# Excel - Looking up for next available data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find lookup for a value corresponding to a cell. The problem is that in the lookup table, there can be multiple rows with the same name, and the lookup value can have a blank as well.

Consider a hypothetical situation - 
[image: Finding the first car owned]

This is a very poorly ordered data with **the first table showing** - Record for cars bought by Dave, John and Kim at any point of time (if they did not buy any, it is just left blank).

**The second table** contains the output table, which has the info for the first car bought by each of the people mentioned above. The text in green shows the finial desired value.

Please help me in getting the desired data.

Comment: VLOOKUP would only give the first match right?
Which in case of Dave would be a blank cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$13)/(($B$2:$B$13<>"")*($A$2:$A$13 = D2)),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I really need to start to look at this `AGGREGATE` function.  Looks way more sleek than array formula.

Comment: @ian0411 it is an inherent array formula, no CSE but one should still limit the reference range.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**REVISED:**

Need to give @ScottCraner credit to help me shorten the formula.  :P

My brain is not clear this morning.  Forgot how to shorten this one but I really need to get a newer version of Excel (Excel 2007 in my PC).

Here is the **array formula** (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) you can try in case you don't have `AGGREGATE` function:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$13<>"")*($A$2:$A$13 = D2),ROW($B$2:$B$13)),1),1),"")
```